# Power series expansion answer different

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Power series expansion of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{3-z}$$ around $4i$.

I calculated the radius of convergence to be $5$, and I obtained the power series:

$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!(z-4i)^n}{(3-z)^{-(n+1)}}$$

The answer key has the same, except they don't have my $n!$ term. Why? What have I done wrong?

$$f=\frac{1}{3-z}$$
$$f^{(1)}=(3-z)^{-2}$$
$$f^{(2)}=2(3-z)^{-3}$$
$$f^{(3)}=6(3-z)^{-4}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$f^{(n)}=n!(3-z)^{-(n+1)}$$
It would seem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coefficient of $(x-a)^n$ in the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $x=a$ is $f^{(n)}(a)/n!$.  You forgot to divide by $n!$.

Comment: Yes, true, thank you, I'm silly!